# Google sheet query 2 columns as search key and search

Tags: google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I met some problem with google sheet function.

I have 2 tables. I want to search table1 Date+User as key value in table2.
example:

```
Date      User  Unit
2022/05/30  A   109
2022/05/30  B   119
2022/05/30  C   119
2022/05/29  D   109
2022/05/29  E   114

Date      User  Amount
2022/05/30  A   1
2022/05/30  B   2
2022/05/30  C   3
2022/05/30  D   41
2022/05/30  E   5
2022/05/29  D   6
2022/05/29  E   7
2022/05/29  F   81
2022/05/29  G   9
2022/05/29  A   101
2022/05/29  B   11
2022/05/29  C   121
2022/05/29  D   13
```

after query I hope the table looks like

```
Hope Result         
Date       User Unit    Amount
2022/05/30  A   109       1
2022/05/30  B   119       2
2022/05/30  C   119       3
2022/05/29  D   109       6
2022/05/29  E   114       7
```

This is a sample google sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oxhWMVPt-GziG10agob-xbiNYfKrZVFK9ro0Pj7tn6Y/edit#gid=0

Can I ask for help ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options. The first pulls all matching combinations of DATE and USER

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  QUERY(
   {E2:G,
    IF(ISBLANK(E2:E),,
     IFERROR(
      VLOOKUP(
       E2:E&"|"&F2:F,
       {A2:A&"|"&B2:B,C2:C},
       2,FALSE)))},
   "select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col3
    where Col4 is not null
    label
     Col1 'Date',
     Col2 'User',
     Col3 'Amount',
     Col4 'Unit'"))
```

which returns

| Date | User | Unit | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/05/30 | A | 109 | 1 |
| 2022/05/30 | B | 119 | 2 |
| 2022/05/30 | C | 119 | 3 |
| 2022/05/29 | D | 109 | 6 |
| 2022/05/29 | E | 114 | 7 |
| 2022/05/29 | D | 109 | 13 |

The second matches your output exactly, but does omit that second D value for the 29th (13)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  QUERY(
   {IFERROR(
     VLOOKUP(
      UNIQUE(E2:E&"|"&F2:F),
      {E2:E&"|"&F2:F,E2:G},
      {2,3,4},FALSE)),
    IFERROR(
     VLOOKUP(
      UNIQUE(E2:E&"|"&F2:F),
      {A2:A&"|"&B2:B,C2:C},
      2,FALSE))},
   "where Col4 is not null
    format Col1 'yyyy/mm/dd'"))
```

Both have been added to your sheet. If either of these work out for you, I can break it down.